# Paypal button shows empty shopping cart

Tags: html, paypal

Why does this give me an empty shopping cart ? A single item works just fine.

Any ideas anyone, if it helps (or doesnt) PayPal support could not help either.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.net">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Shopping Cart">

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />

    <input type="hidden" name="display" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="12.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="45.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="6.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="17.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_5" value="98.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="ADCDE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="DEFGH" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="KLMNO" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="PQRST" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="STUVW" />


    <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://xxxxxxx.co.uk/images/50x50.jpg" />

    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://xxxxxxx.co.uk">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified two conflicting actions (display and upload). Remove the display command and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a method to your first form tag as in action="https://PayPal.com/blBlabla " method="post"